# After 19.10 installed, can't boot 18.04

Tags: boot, 19.10

I have a computer with multiple operating systems:
sda1   Windows
sda7   Ubuntu 16.04
sda8   Ubuntu 19.04
sdb4   Ubuntu 19.10  (new install, was 19.04)
sdb7   Ubuntu 18.04

After 19.10 was installed, I can't boot either sdb7-18.04 or sda8-19.04.
I always have to edit the grub file every time I install a new system because the wrong partitions/kernels are selected (bug in grub or prober).  I do this using Grub Customizer.  But this time I can't get it to work at all.  Even using the code from an old working version of grub.cfg for 18.04 no longer works.
However, I can boot 16.04.  The only difference I can find is the location of the /boot.  In 16.04 /boot is in the same partition as the root.  All the others use sdb2 which is used only as a boot partition.

I tried using boot-repair, but still can't find any menu entry which boots 18.04.

Any suggestions?

I tried reinstalling 19.04 twice.  In both cases I could now boot 19.04 but still could not boot 18.04.  The first time I did not specify a /boot partition and the second time I specified sdb2 which had not worked but now works.
I saw two error messages which I had not previously seen with 18.04.  The first was with /boot in the root partition.  The message was "UUID  f1087...f5c5 does not exist".  I checked with disks and the partition does exist; the correct partition was in the grub.cfg file.  The second message was with /boot in a separate partition.  This message was "Failed to start Load Kernel Modules".

It seems that I could install 18.04 again and everything would work.  If I don't get any better ideas, I will try that in a day or two.

Comment: Have you tried running sudo update-grub from Ubuntu 19.10? I haven't experienced the bug you are referring to, but like you, i also have multiple operating systems on various partitions, but in my case, update-grub (os prober) works every time. Can you post the output of the following:
sudo fdisk -l
sudo update-grub
as well as the relevant contents of your grub.cfg? I am curious how any why the drive and partition numbers aren't being detected properly. Be aware, that the BIOS or EFI Setup specifies the relevant boot drive, for both EFI as well as Legacy based systems, so if for some reason, y

Comment: When you boot into 16.04 and 19.04 do both reveal all the same partitions for `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,MOUNTPOINT,SIZE,MODEL |egrep -v "^loop"`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix   I see the same partitions from 16.04 and 19.10.  I have done more tests and will add these to my original post

Comment: @ChasW  I get the same problem with update-grub ; the wrong kernel or UUID are specified.  For example when I reinstalled 19.04 with the /boot in sdb2 then I could not boot 19.04.  I had to boot 16.04 and edit the file grub.cfg in sdb2.  The line starting " linux /vmlinuz-"  contains the kernel to be booted and the UUID for the partition.  The install had chosen the kernel for 19.10 in the partition for 19.04.  Sometimes the kernel is wrong, sometimes the partition, sometimes both, and sometimes both are correct.  The file grub.cfg needs to be edited every time a new kernel is installed.